# Substitution on range of lines

Tags: linux, sed

I have `<host></host>` in 3rd line of a file. I want to replace that with `<host>my_dB</host>`. How to do this with `sed`. I want to do replacements like this in 4th, 5th and 6th line too.

```
<host></host>
<host>my_dB</host>
```

Comment: The title ask for lines `3-6` to be modified but the question only asks for `3-5`? It should be clear how to change the range with the given answers though.

Comment: i forget to specify 6th. forgive me..ur soln was brief and clear, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each can be done with something similar to this:

```
sed -i "s/<host><\/host>/<host>my_db<\/host>/" foo.txt
```

The `-i` means that it'll overwrite the file in-place. Remove that flag to have the changes written to stdout.

If this is for a regular task to fill in details for the file, consider adding anchors to the file to make it easier. For example:

```
<host>DB_HOST</host>
```

Then the sed would just need to be:

```
sed -i 's/DB_HOST/my_db/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
$ sed '3,6 s/<host>/<host>my_dB/' file
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file
1: <host></host>
2: <host></host>
3: <host></host>
4: <host></host>
5: <host></host>
6: <host></host>
7: <host></host>

$ sed '3,6 s/<host>/<host>my_dB/' file
1: <host></host>
2: <host></host>
3: <host>my_dB</host>
4: <host>my_dB</host>
5: <host>my_dB</host>
6: <host>my_dB</host>
```

7:

To store the changes back to the file use the `-i` option

```
$ sed -i '3,6 s/<host>/<host>my_bd/' file
```

However you really should be using a XML parser. Getting into parsing XML with `regexp` is really a bad idea.

Comment: @@sudo_O---I am running a cap task to do this..Dnt think i could use XML parser there...

Comment: I don't what a `cap task` is? In this case it might be a quick fix to modified the file with `sed` but generally if you need to edit `XML` you should use a parser and not regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

To replace all instances of `<host></host>` with `<host>my_dB</host>` in your file, run:

```
sed 's|<host></host>|<host>my_dB</host>|g' file
```

Comment: Wow, It worked,tats a different way to think..thank you, thanks a lot

Comment: @kate this does the substitution on every line not just lines 3 to 6.

Comment: @@sudo_O--luckily the tag names are not repeated. DBname, host, userName, password..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 sed -r '3,5s#(<host>)(</host>)#\1my_dB\2#' file
```

Comment: i get cmd failed. '\\''sed -r '\\''3,5s#(<host>)(</host>)#\001my_dB\002#'\\''

Comment: @Kent--tats wat i get buddy...anyway my issue is solved nw. thanks anyway